# PySpark Filtering, Is 5 > NULL True or False or Ignored?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In Pyspark, let's say we are comparing values in 2 columns such as:

```
df = df.filter(F.col(1) > F.col(2))
```

If Col 1 has the value 5, and Col 2 has the value NULL, what will happen? Will it be filtered or not?

Does this evaluate to true or false or nothing?

Comment: [Null handling in comparison operators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-null-semantics.html#comp-operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will evaluate to false. You are trying to compare a value with null, which is a null pointer.

To emulate the same:

Preparing data

```
case class Test(t1:Int,t2:Int)
var df = Seq(Test(1,1),Test(2,0),Test(3,3)).toDF
df.show(false)
```

+---+---+
|t1 |t2 |
+---+---+
|1  |1  |
|2  |0  |
|3  |3  |
+---+---+

Comparing not null data

```
df.filter($"t1">$"t2").show(false)
```

+---+---+
|t1 |t2 |
+---+---+
|2  |0  |
+---+---+

Adding a column with null

```
df=df.withColumn("t3",lit(null))
df.show(false)
```

+---+---+----+
|t1 |t2 |t3  |
+---+---+----+
|1  |1  |null|
|2  |0  |null|
|3  |3  |null|
+---+---+----+

Comparing with null

```
df.filter($"t1">$"t3").show(false)
```

+---+---+---+
|t1 |t2 |t3 |
+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+